# Why almost sure convergence holds if $X_n = n$ w.p. $1/n$?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, almost-everywhere, borel-cantelli-lemmas

I've encountered these two examples (used to show how a.s. convergence doesn't imply convergence in $R$th mean and visa versa). In one case we have a random variable $X_n = n$ with probability $\frac{1}{n}$ and zero otherwise (so with probability $1-\frac{1}{n}$). In another case same deal with only difference being $X_n=1$, not $n$ with probability $\frac{1}{n}$. Assume $X_n$'s are independent in both.

It is clear to me that in the second case, where $X_n = 1$ w.p.  $\frac{1}{n}$, the summation is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(X_n=1) =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} =\infty $, so by Borel Cantelli Lemma 1 we have that "$X_n=1$" occurs infinitely often and hence $X_n$ doesn't converge almost surely to zero.

In the first case however, where $X_n = n$ w.p. $\frac{1}{n}$, the argument goes that $X_n$ converges to zero almost surely. Why is that? Isn't it the same, only here we are summing $P(X_n \ne 0)$ for $n=1$ through $\infty$ and these probabilities are again resulting in a diverging harmonic series?

Comment: Can you please clarify what exactly your question is ?

Comment: If you have understood one case properly, I'll suggest that you should remove that part, and write only those portions which you're doubtful about.

Comment: hi, apologies for a typo - corrected now in the original question. so my question is how the first case converges to zero, while in the second case we have no convergence. i would think in both cases we should have our sequence of random variables diverging.

Answer (score 1):

Sure there is a typo in the textbook. The first case is, for example, $X_n=\frac{1}{n}$ w.p. $\frac{1}{n}$ and zero elsewhere.

This sequence converges