# For $X_1,\dots, X_n$ independent distributed with $P(X_n=0) = 1-\frac1n; P(X_n=n) = \frac1n$, does $X_n$ converge to $0$ almost surely?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, borel-cantelli-lemmas

I am referring to a question that has already been asked, but not completely answered ([Why almost sure convergence holds if $X_n = n$ w.p. $1/n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3945651)).

For $X_1,\dots, X_n$ independent distributed with $P(X_n=0) = 1-\frac1n; P(X_n=n) = \frac1n$, does $X_n$ converge to $0$ almost surely?

My guess would be that is does not since we can apply the second Borel-Cantelli Lemma like in this very similar and well known example: [If $(X_n)$ is independent with $X_n$ Bernoulli of parameter $\frac1n$, how to show that $X_n$ doesn't converge almost surely to $0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1954638/if-x-n-is-independent-with-x-n-bernoulli-of-parameter-frac1n-how-to-sh?rq=1)

If it does in fact not converge almost surely to $0$ is it also the case that is does not converge to zero almost surely?

Comment: Pointwise convergence implies almost surely convergent. Isn't $X_n\overset{\text{p.w.}}\rightarrow0$?

Comment: @PNDas that is basically an extension of my question, but I don't think so, because $X_n=n$ can occur after all, right?

Comment: In the answer of the question you linked, They said that there is a typo and $X_n=\frac1n$. Sorry I didn't read your question completely.

Comment: @PNDas yes, thank you I read that in the original question, but this statement doesn't seem to have been written with much confidence and there is no proof or explanation provided. Also this remark mentions $X_n=1/n$ and not $X_n=n$. Basically, I just want to know if the Borel-Cantelli Theorem applies in the same way for this series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right: the falseness of the claim follows from the second Borel-Cantelli Lemma. Since the $X_n$ are independent and
$$\sum_n \mathbb{P}(X_n=n)=\sum_n \frac{1}{n}=+\infty$$
then with probability $1$ we have $X_n=n$ infinitely often, which means that in fact almost surely $X_n$ does not converge to $0$.